# When Did Structures Begin to Orbit in the Universe?

Tags: cosmology, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

In Big Bang Cosmology, I am familiar with the radiation era, and the moment of last scattering, but I am just not familiar with the physics of orbits, or of the “falling outward,“ if you will, that would have triggered this momentum in the Universe.  Structures as we know them would need to have formed, for their orbits to begin... But I think this gets lost in the details... With all the meandering around evolved classical objects one has to endure, one never sees the Universe conceptually in it's dance. Structures orbit, and when could this have begun?... In relation to structure formation and formation of filaments that would become galaxies...

Comment: Minutephysics has great video about it, with links in the description. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmNXKqeUtJM

Comment: Thank you for your reply... That is a very informative video. It complements what I'm studying about the Epic of Reionization, into the forming of first structures... The video, however, as with the rest of physics I've run into, however, only hints at why thins spin... with the informing caveat over why things decide to be flat in a 3+1 dimensional universe. I'll assume that it is in the fundamentals of the baryons... toward and through the activity of the pre-quasar `blobs` where the or oral motion begins... and will become more pronounced with the arrow of time...

Comment: Was trying to edit on a Kindle and the site cut me off... Hope my reply is understandable... Cheers!